# Like button code doesn't work on my website

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-java-api

I found a few similar topics however none specific to my issue. I went to create a like button code, I clicked the create like box, added my link http://www.facebook.com/pages/SpartaPerformancecom/248083571902684 to the URL formated the like button how I want it to appear. Then I opened Dreamweaver and pasted the Facebook code in the Dreamweaver HTML code where I want the Like button to appear but I get nothing. Please respond like "coding for dummies" language so I can understand how to solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the code you are attempting to use?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `<div id="fb-root"></div>`  somewhere between the `<body></body>` tags. Their latest like button generator is missing that part.